Does local parametrization for pure-dimensional germs require a general position condition?
Background
Following Gunning's book, Introduction to Holomorphic Functions of Several Variables, Vol II, one has the following result (Lemma E.12) given as a corollary of the Local Parametrization Theorem.
Lemma. Each point $A$ on a holomorphic variety $V$ has arbitrarily small open neighborhoods of the form $V_A = V_1 \cup \dots \cup V_r$ where $V_j$ are holomorphic varieties representing the irreducible components of the germ of the variety $V$ at the point $A$ and each $V_j$ can be represented as a finite branched holomorphic covering of a polydisc with the point $A\in V_j$ as the only point lying over the center of the polydisc.
The dimension of the complex space $\mathbb{C}^{n_j}$ where the image polydisc $D_j$ has $D_j \subseteq \mathbb{C}^{n_j}$ is naturally $n_j = \dim_A(V_j)$ for each $V_j$. In fact, it appears on an inspection of the proof that the following is correct or close to correct, which I'd like to know as a technical lemma in a longer analysis. One can understand the result as wanting to know that a projection chosen by populating a matrix of the correct size with coefficients at uniform random yields a local parametrization:
Corollary. If $V$ is a holomorphic subvariety of an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^N$ with notation otherwise as in the above Lemma and the germ of $V$ at $A$ has pure dimension $d$, then there is a Zariski open subset of linear projections $\mathbb{C}^N\to\mathbb{C}^d$ where $\pi\vert_{V_A}$ is a finite branched holomorphic covering of its image with the properties described in the Lemma for all sufficiently small neighborhoods $V_A$ for any $\pi$ in the subset.
One may assume $A$ is the origin for convenience. The idea of the proof here is supposed to run fairly straightforwardly:

The covering which exists by the Lemma is the restriction of a full rank linear projection with the domain and codomain described, particularly because all the irreducible components have the same dimension,
A full rank linear projection is of the necessary type to fulfill the Lemma if it fulfills an open condition [described briefly below],
The map $\pi\vert_{V_A}$ is a finite branched covering in particular because it has a branch locus consisting of $(\cup_{j} B_j) \cup  (\cup_{i\not= j} V_i \cap V_j )$ where the $B_j$ are branch locuses for $\pi\vert_{V_j}$.

Regarding the condition on $\pi$: If $\pi$ is of full rank we can factor $\pi = p \circ \rho$ where $p$ is the natural projection $\mathbb{C}^N\to\mathbb{C}^{d}$ onto the first $d$ components and $\rho:\mathbb{C}^N\to\mathbb{C}^N$ is linear and nonsingular. The condition is that the prime ideal $\text{id} (\rho(V_j)) \subseteq _N\mathcal{O}_0$ is "regular in the variables $z_{d+1},\dots,z_{N}$" for each $V_j$. Note that $_N\mathcal{O}_0$ is the ring of germs of holomorphic functions of $\mathbb{C}^N$ at the origin and for $j < N$ that $_j\mathcal{O}_0$ is the subring of germs of functions in the first $j$ variables.
For the sake of completeness: An ideal $\mathfrak{U} \subseteq _N\mathcal{O}_0$ is regular in the variables $z_{d+1},\dots,z_{N}$ if:

$_d\mathcal{O}_0 \cap\mathfrak{U} = 0$ (i.e., none of the functions in the ideal are independent of the variables $z_{d+1},\dots,z_N$) and
There is an element $\mathbf{f}_j\in\text{ } _j\mathcal{O}_0$ that is regular in $z_j$ for each $j$ with $d+1 \leq j \leq N$.

A germ $\mathbf{f} \in \text{ } _j\mathcal{O}_0$ of holomorphic functions is regular in $z_j$ if it has a representative $f$ that is regular in $z_j$, in the sense that $f(0,\dots,0,z_j)$ as a function of $z_j$ alone is not identically zero on some open neighborhood of the origin.
I have a gap in my understanding of this regularity condition. You can regard this as not being certain that step (2) in the proof of the above Corollary is correct as stated, i.e., that some additional conditions are required on the germ of $V$ at $A$ to ensure that there really is an open subset of projections which suffice. One has the following, which seems weaker than what I'd like:

(Lemma D4) Any finite list of ideals in $_N\mathcal{O}_0$ can be made simultaneously regular in some set of variables $z_{d+1},\dots,z_N$ by a suitable nonsingular linear change of coordinates in $\mathbb{C}^N$.
(Following from Lemma D5) If $C_1$ is a nonsingular $d\times d$ matrix and $C_2$ a nonsingular $(N-d)\times (N-d)$ matrix, then if $\mathfrak{U}$ is regular in $z_{d+1},\dots,z_{N}$ and $(z_1,\dots,z_N)^T\mapsto (C_1 \oplus C_2)(z_1,\dots,z_N)^T = (z_1',\dots,z_N')^T$ is a nonsingular linear change of variables then the ideal $\mathfrak{U}$ is also regular in $z_{d+1}',\dots,z_N'$.

The linear changes of coordinates in the second bullet point are obviously not an open subset. I don't have access to the proof of the first bullet (it's in Gunning's Vol 1), so it's not clear to me whether "suitable" is an open condition or not.
Question
Ultimately, I'm interested in the following: Is the Corollary correct as stated, or is there some additional constraint on the germ of $V$ at $A$ which one must require to get its full strength? As in the top line question, I've seen "general position" conditions for irreducible components thrown around in some contexts that strike me as a possibility, but not in a format that has cleared up this question for me.

If someone who feels confident wants to edit the tags, please go ahead and do so. Several-complex-variables is clearly the "canonical" tag here, but I added some other more active ones somewhat speculatively.
